# Converter RTSP stream para HTTP Live Stream

Tags: ios, http, streaming

Como faço para converter RTSP stream para HTTP Live stream?

Possuo uma IP Câmera que usa o protocolo RTSP para realizar streaming de vídeo, e gostaria de fazer ele funcionar no iOS utilizando o navegador Safari. Segundo a documentação do Safari <sup>1</sup>

> Safari on the desktop plays the RTSP stream, while **Safari on iOS plays
>   the HTTP Live stream.**

O navegador no iOS só suporta o protocolo HTTP Live stream. Como converter esse fluxo?

1 <sub>[Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html)</sub>

Comment: Veja se os links abaixo podem te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370742/convert-rtsp-video-stream-to-http-stream https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/

Comment: Seu desktop é osx?

Comment: Sim, Thiago. Yosemite.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660113/how-to-convert-rtsp-streaming-to-http-live-streaming-using-lighttpd

Answer (score 1):

Como mencionado, pode-se fazer funcionar com VLC ou ffmpeg. Não sei exatamente os comandos para usá-los, então vou dar uma terceira opção: GStreamer

Verifique se seu SO tem algum pacote de instalação para GStreamer (acredito que não tem para OS/X), se não tiver você pode instalar baixando da URL abaixo:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/

Num terminal, você pode testar se seu sistema consegue decodificar o stream RTSP usando:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri="<url do stream>"
```

Se executar corretamente então tudo certo. Caso contrário, pode ser que a versão que você instalou não tenha suporte ao formato usado ou você esbarrou em algum bug. Pode reportar em http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer

Tendo executado corretamente, você precisa agora fazer a transcodificação para HLS

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri="<url do stream>" name=d ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! hlssink d. ! queue ! audioconvert ! faac ! queue ! mux.
```

Você pode usar gst-inspect-1.0 hlssink para ver algumas propriedades que você pode adicionar ao hlssink e configurar o local da playlist HLS e outros detalhes se quiser. O default vai ser que os arquivos para o HLS vão ser colocados na pasta onde você executar o comando.

Agora você precisa executar um servidor HTTP para servir os arquivos gerados. O mais simples seria:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

e vai iniciar um servidor na porta 8000, ai basta você apontar o cliente para http://ip.do.seu.desktop:8000/playlist.m3u8